# Is the word '딴' related to 다르다?

Tags: word-origin

Superficially, 딴 meaning (an)other sounds like a shortened version of 다른 (different). Is there an etymological relationship or is the similarity in sound and meaning just a coincidence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the 표준국어대사전, the etymological origin of 딴 is:

> ᄠᆞㄹ+ㄴ -> ᄠᆞㄴ -> 딴.

Given that the 아래 아 (ᆞ) often became ㅏ (hence its name 아래 아), and the fact there was a ㄹ in the original word, and that it was common for the letter ㄷ to strengthen to ㄸ, I'd say it seems pretty likely that they have the same origin.  But they don't mention explicitly a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

There is an adjective '따다' which means '다르다' mainly used in a 함경 (in North Korea) dialect. '딴' seems to be derived from this adjective.

The important thing is '딴' and '다른' don't have the exact same connotation. '딴' is used for a rather *completely* different thing while '다른' is used for a different thing, but it is a little related. In other words, '딴' is **more emphatic** than '다른'. It's **not easy to tell the difference** as there is very little difference between them,  but I will try.

> 딴 생각 말고 공부나 해. (Literally) Don't think about completely different (unrelated) things and study.
>
> 다른 생각 말고 공부나 해. (Literally) Don't think about different (unrelated) things and study.

The first sentence is used when a speaker worries that a listener might think about things that are completely unrelated with studying. Therefore, using the first sentence is more emphatic and strong.

> 너 지금 딴 생각 하지? (Literally) Are you doing a completely different
>   thinking?
>
> 너 지금 다른 생각 하지? (Literally) Are you doing a different thinking?

The linked [우리말 바로쓰기 on "딴 사람 vs 단 사람"](http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=4294) have some more examples. But you will find it very difficult to understand the subtle difference.

Comment: Examples could be improved...

Comment: It's not clear how `thinking about different things` is different from `thinking about completely different things` when one should be studying. IMO both sentences carry same meaning.

Comment: @qarma Does the edit improve the answer?

Comment: Not really, adding `(literally)` to both sentences doesn't make a contrast. Could it be along the lines of `Don't think about anything else (e.g. boys), just study English` vs `Don't think about other subjects (e.g. Chinese), just study English`?